# Create slide in flutter with multi carousel flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create a slider like this:

[image]

But in reality I did not do very well. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) package, and this package has a similar solution and very customizable

Answer (score 0):

You can try `PageView`. Then `Transform` the item with animation

```
PageView.builder(
                controller: controller,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                  return AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: controller,
                    builder: (_, c) {
                      double value = 1.0;
                      value = controller.page - i;
                      value = (1 - (value.abs() * .2)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);

                      double dx = ((1 - value) * 100).toDouble();

                      if (controller.page - i < 0) {
                        dx = -dx;
                      }
                      double dy = -(1 - value) * 200;
                      return Transform.translate(
                          offset: Offset(dx, dy),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.green[300],
                              border: Border.all(),
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            child: ls[i],
                          ),
                        );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
```